# Magento2 : Set Customer Custom Attribute Value Using Rest API

Tags: magento2, customer, api, rest-api

Property **"Mobilenumber"** does not have accessor method "getMobilenumber" in class "**Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface**".

Whenever i am trying to set customer custom attribute value i am getting above error.
does anyone know how to save customer custom attribute value using REST API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the answer, you should have to use below code to update customer custom attribute

```
$customAttributeValues=array("attributeCode" => "mobilenumber", "value" => "918985552230");

$customerData = [
    'customer' => [
        'id' => 5,
        "email" => "test@example.com",
        "firstname" => "Magecomp",
        "lastname" => "Tester",
        "storeId" => 1,
        "websiteId" => 1,
        "customAttributes" => [$customAttributeValues],
    ]
];

$ch = curl_init("http://127.0.0.1/m232/rest/V1/customers/5");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```